# How to efficiently generate unique random non-zero integers from specific spaces in a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate 100 pairs of unique random non-zero integers from the range (-150, 151). But I want my code to generate from specific areas in (-150, 151). I have coded it as follows:

```
import random

my_list = []
c = 0
while c < 100:
    if c < 5:
        # Both values are unique.
        first_num, second_num = random.sample(range(-5, 6), 2)
        # Exclusion of 0.
        while first_num == 0 or second_num == 0:
            first_num, second_num = random.sample(range(-5, 6), 2)
        c += 1
    elif 5 <= c < 80:
        first_num, second_num = random.sample(range(-100, 101), 2)
        while first_num == 0 or second_num == 0:
            first_num, second_num = random.sample(range(-100, 101), 2)
        c += 1
    else:
        first_num, second_num = random.sample(range(-150, 151), 2)
        while first_num == 0 or second_num == 0:
            first_num, second_num = random.sample(range(-150, 151), 2)
        c += 1

    random_nums = (first_num, second_num)
    if random_nums not in my_list:
        my_list.append(random_nums)
    else:
        c -= 1
```

Is there a more elegant or efficient way alternative to what I have coded above?

**UPDATE**

After discussing with MatBailie in the comments, I am updating the requirements:

If the whole selected range is (-150 to 151), then in the final `my_list`:

- (5,6), (6,5) are allowed but (5,6), (5,6) are not.
- If (-1, 1) is generated once from range (-5 to 6) then it should not be generated again from the bigger ranges such as (-100 to 101) or (-150 to 151)
- It is also good to have pairs such as (-1, 140) or (140, -1).

**UPDATE**

Benchmarking MatBailie, Alain T. and Samwise's answers on [perfpy](https://perfpy.com/) with 100 pairs, I got the following result:

[image]

The same benchmark with generating 1000 pairs and the same ratio of areas, I got this:

[image]

Comment: So are you saying you would like 5 numbers in range of -5 to +5 excluding 0, 75 numbers in the range -100 to +100 excluding 0, and 20 numbers in  the range -150 to +150, excluding 0?  and no number is repeated or no combination of numbers are repeated?

Comment: @itprorh66 Correct.

Comment: @MatBailie Good point. I think at the end I should add `else: c -= 1`. I just edited the code.

Comment: @MatBailie No. Both are allowed to be present in the final `my_list`.

Comment: @itprorh66 Following MatBailie's comment, (5,6) and (5,6) are not allowed but (5,6) and (6, 5) are allowed.

Comment: @MatBailie In the larger range (-150, 150) it is better not to have pairs such as (-1,1) but good to have for example (-1, 140). But I didn't know how to manage it.

Comment: @MatBailie If (140,-1) or (-1,140) can't be generated then don't consider either tuple.

Comment: @MatBailie What do you exactly mean by *"don't allow any pairs a smaller range could have generated?"*

Comment: You said the larger range of (-150 to 150) ***should not*** be able to generate (-1, 1). Is that because the smaller range (-5 to 5) ***could*** generate that pair?

Comment: @MatBailie Correct.

Comment: Your edit to the question isn't what I said. Your question now forbids (-150 to 150) from generating (-1, 1) if it's already been generated. My understanding of your comments is that you said (-150 to 150) shouldn't ***ever*** generate (-1, 1) regardless of whether it had already been generated or not.

Comment: @MatBailie Another good question. They should be symmetric. I'll edit the code to include the upper bound too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's gone past midnight, but I'll do my best to explain...

The basic principle is that I work out how many different pairs there are in a given range (excluding any zeros), and run a sample on that range, so I know there are no duplicates.

Then I code a function to "decode" those integers in to a pairs.

So, if I want a pair with elements in the range -4 to +4, excluding zeros, excluding pairs from the range -2 to +2, I can map that to a grid of possible pairs...

```
    -4  -3  -2  -1  +0  +1  +2  +3  +4

+4   O   O   O   O   X   O   O   O   O
+3   O   O   O   O   X   O   O   O   O
+2   O   O   X   X   X   X   X   O   O 
+1   O   O   X   X   X   X   X   O   O 
+0   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
-1   O   O   X   X   X   X   X   O   O 
-2   O   O   X   X   X   X   X   O   O 
-3   O   O   O   O   X   O   O   O   O
-4   O   O   O   O   X   O   O   O   O
```

O = Possible pair
X = Excluded pair

There are 48 allowed possible pairs.

- 48 = (4² - 2²) * 4

I then write a function that can turn each of the values 0..47 in to a different one of those allowed possible pairs.

```
import random
from pprint import pprint

def decode(val, lower, upper):
  q = val % 4
  v = val >> 2
  
  x = v % (upper + lower) - lower
  if x >= 0:
    x += 1
  y = v // (upper + lower) + lower + 1
  
  if q in (1,3):
    x = -x
    y = -y
  
  if q in (2,3):
    x,y = -y,x

  return (x,y)

def pairs(n, lower, upper):
  return [
    decode(id, lower, upper)
      for id in random.sample(
        range((upper**2 - lower**2) * 4),
        n
      )
  ]

# smaller ranges used to make it printable and testable
result = [
  *pairs( 5,  0,  5),  # 5 pairs with values in the range - 5 to  5, except pairs using the range - 0 to 0
  *pairs( 5,  5, 10),  # 5 pairs with values in the range -10 to 10, except pairs using the range - 5 to 5 
  *pairs( 5, 10, 20)   # 5 pairs with values in the range -20 to 20, except pairs using the range -10 to 10 
]

pprint(result)
```

Demo : https://trinket.io/python3/f9e65fe9ef

Comment: Regardless of implementation, this style of approach is always the correct one (determine state space, sample from it).  Otherwise 'random' quickly loses meaning.
Depending on the size of the space and the exceptions, `randomAnything + retryBad` can also be efficient, and is often correct.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution. There is only a typo in the last row of the grid in your answer, instead of +4 it should be -4. Please have a look at the benchmark results in the second update to my question.

Comment: @plpm - I'm surprised that this performs best at 100 pairs, I had thought the decode() overhead would be higher. This answer does have a scaling advantage, however, because it never generates duplicates; so, it avoids the while loops (the larger the number of pairs, the more duplicates need regenerating, the incrementally slower the other implementations will get). BUT when the run time is measured in milliseconds, I don't think that matters. I'd prioritise maintainability and flexibility above runtime, unless you're planning to generate millions of pairs over large ranges.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a list of the 100 ranges repeating the same ones in groups of the required size.  This will make the rest of the logic more generalized and simpler:

```
import random
   
ranges = [range(-5,6)]*5 + [range(-100,101)]*75 + [range(-150,151)]*20
pairs  = []
for R in ranges:
    a = 0
    while not a or not b or (a,b) in pairs:
        a,b = random.sample(R,2)  # random.choices(R,k=2)
    pairs.append((a,b))
```

output:

```
print(pairs)

[(-3, 2), (-3, -5), (3, 1), (-4, -3), (2, 4), (-73, -9), (16, -56),
 (12, -81), (5, -50), (99, -6), (35, 71), (30, -75), (98, 25), (55, -58), 
 (73, -24), (-65, 4), (75, -96), (-6, -90), (-80, 22), (-93, -39), 
 (-69, -48), (-30, 25), (85, -11), (37, 60), (91, 96), (98, 100), 
 (-100, -54), (58, 20), (-14, -95), (-76, -12), (-5, -84), (70, -53), 
 (91, -66), (-61, 2), (4, -42), (-15, -70), (-52, -6), (-5, 93), (26, 76),
 (-8, -79), (63, -7), (-23, -27), (56, 13), (46, 27), (80, 94), (-94, -66), 
 (-46, -19), (-4, -87), (-92, -48), (24, 32), (10, -89), (-50, -96),   
 (-5, -85), (-32, 69), (-60, 69), (87, -81), (-100, -91), (87, 37), 
 (-60, 45), (-70, -84), (-98, 80), (-88, 57), (-67, -44), (-72, 4), 
 (-76, 5), (-79, -16), (-9, 80), (76, -41), (15, 77), (-47, -1), (58, 12), 
 (66, -2), (21, 16), (-24, -12), (54, -69), (58, -73), (61, 68), (-89, -37), 
 (-85, 68), (-7, -21), (-86, -31), (48, 136), (137, 86), (-61, -32), 
 (104, -144), (-24, -103), (80, 135), (-2, 39), (49, -21), (15, -103), 
 (-14, -145), (-48, -61), (142, -90), (93, -132), (-68, -111), (-80, 2), 
 (6, 45), (-89, 75), (-146, -76), (-94, -24)]
```

You could also do this using only one list by initializing the resulting list with ranges that you replace with the generated pairs:

```
pairs = [range(-5,6)]*5 + [range(-100,101)]*75 + [range(-150,151)]*20
for i,R in enumerate(pairs):
    pairs[i] = (0,0)
    while not all(pairs[i]) or pairs.index(pairs[i])<i:
        pairs[i] = random.sample(R,2) # random.choices(R,k=2)
```

Comment: Although also used by the OP, sample(R, 2) will never pick (1,1) or (2,2) etc, which I don't believe is intended? Otherwise, very concise!

Comment: Good catch.  I added `# random.choices(R,k=2)` to indicate the alternative

Answer (score 1):

I might do it like this, using a list of numbers to be able to take the `sample` without having to take an extra step of dropping the zeroes, and using a dict to enforce uniqueness (a set would be simpler, but a dict preserves insertion order, which is important if you want the same arrangement of the different samples in the final list, with smaller numbers toward the beginning):

```
import random

max_num = 150
nums = list(range(-max_num, max_num))
nums.remove(0)

my_list = list({
    tuple(
        random.sample(nums[max_num-r:r-max_num or None], 2)
    ): 0
    for c, r in ((5, 5), (75, 100), (20, 150))
    for _ in range(c)
})
```

Generating a single `nums` list is a little more complicated than generating a new list for each sample population, but is more efficient since then we don't need to repeatedly re-allocate it, and can simply take slices as needed.

Note that `max_num` needs to be at least as big as all of the `r` values in the `for c, r` iteration, or we won't be able to get the desired range by slicing `nums` with `max_num-r` etc.

Comment: OP now wants duplicates regenerated, not just eliminated.

Comment: Only the first answer is free.

Comment: That's why I ask questions in comments. Too many questions don't actually cover all the OP's requirements. Consultant, contractor, SO answerer, same skepticism required ;)

Comment: Yeah, I only do the work of bludgeoning requirements out of a client (always harder on me than it is on them) when I'm actually going to get paid for it.  ;)